# Dijkstra on adjacency matrix in C

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, dijkstra

I need some help with Dijkstra's algorithm in C.

I've generated my adjacency matrix, that looks something like:

```
int mat[NB][NB] =  {{0, 171, MAX, 132, [...]}, {171, 0, 30, 39, [...]}, , [...]};
```

I've found this implementation: http://www.answers.com/topic/dijkstra-s-algorithm-1 but the path is an 1-dimensional array and my matrix is a 2-dimensional array.

Is there a way to transform one to another?
Or maybe someone has a method to deal with this kind of matrix.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `mat[0]` to a function expecting an `int *` (and a size), that function can easily treat the 2-dimensional matrix as a 1-dimensional matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foobar(int *arr, int siz) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int mat[10][10] = {{4, -3, 7}, {5}};
    printf("%d\n", foobar(mat[0], 10*10));
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit:** ideone ( http://ideone.com/2mLi7 ) runs the program above without complaints :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, `path` is an array where the output of the algorithm is written. The adjacency matrix in that example is apparently the `dist` 2D array.